# Unexpected max number but correct min number

Tags: python

**What I want to happen:** Print out ('542', '-214')

**What is currently happening:** Prints out ('6', '-214')

I am not sure why the minimum number is correct, but the 6 is being used as maximum.

**My Python code:**

```
def high_and_low(numbers):

    numbers = numbers.split(" ")
    maxNumbers = max(numbers)
    minNumbers = min(numbers)

    numbers = maxNumbers, minNumbers

    return numbers

print(high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"))
```

I have tried changing this to:

```
maxNumbers = int(max(numbers))
minNumbers = int(min(numbers))
```

But the 6 still comes back.

Comment: Because strings, not ints.

Comment: Following jezrael's comment. Replace `numbers.split(" ")` for `map(float, numbers.split())` or `map(int, numbers.split())` and you will be ok.

Comment: You are getting the strings in lexicographical order. That `-214` comes out of `min()` is luck, not due to numerical comparisons. Add in `-1` and it would be returned instead.

Comment: need convert list with `map(int, numbers.split())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):

    numbers = [int(n) for n in numbers.split(" ")]
    maxNumbers = max(numbers)
    minNumbers = min(numbers)

    numbers = maxNumbers, minNumbers

    return numbers

print(high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"))
```

Result:

```
(542, -214)
```

When you tried casting the `max()` and `min()` as `int`, you were too late, as the assessment of the values already occurred based on the rank of the various strings in your list. Casting the values as `int` before assessing their rank is the proper way to get the result you're looking for.

Comment: Good catch. I fixed this.

Comment: and also instead `numbers.split(" ")` is possible use `numbers.split()`

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are sorting strings and not ints.
What you tried doing with`int(max(numbers)) only changes the "maximum string" to an int.

You need to change the values into int before checking for maximum and minimum. This will work:

```
def high_and_low(numbers):

    numbers = [int(x) for x in numbers.split(" ")]
    maxNumbers = max(numbers)
    minNumbers = min(numbers)

    numbers = maxNumbers, minNumbers

    return numbers

print(high_and_low("4 5 29 54 4 0 -214 542 -64 1 -3 6 -6"))
```

Answer (score 0):

writing from a mobile device, sorry if formatting sucks. you need cast string values to numeric (integer, float) types.

```
def high_and_low(numbers):
    a =[int(i) for i in numbers.split(" ")]
    return max(a), min(a)
```